# identifying relative clause and noun clause

Tags: nouns, relative-pronouns

> This, it has been argued, is probably true for purely informative advertising, where only the product or store information required to make a rational decision is provided.

I think between **information** and **required** , ***that/which is***  is omitted,
 is this adjectival clause comprised of only **required** or is it comprised of the long phrase **required to make a rational decision**.

> They discussed for a long  time what would be the best epithet to describe a beech-tree.

What is the noun clause in this sentence, is it **what would be the best epithet** or **what would be the best epithet to describe a beech-tree**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, the entire phrase:

> where only the product or store information required to make a rational decision is divided.

is a relative clause that modifies "informative advertising".  In this case the "where" helps mark it as a relative clause.  "In which" could also have been used, as in this similar example:

> The scientists designed a new *process* **where / in which** *they could maintain efficiency but at a much lower temperature.*

In your second example:

> what would be the best epithet to describe a beech-tree

is a noun phrase that describes what they discussed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but is "product or store information" modified by any relative clause in the first sentence?

Comment: @jammyyang   I'm not certain, but while "required to make a rational decision" modifies "product or store information", I think it would be classified as a **participle phrase** (that acts like an adjective) rather than a **relative clause**.

Comment: Thanks ! In terms of how they modify the noun which precedes it , do participle phrase and relative clause have the same function and meaning ?

Comment: @jammyyang  No, they are different parts of speech ... but I can't see that the distinction is all that important.  It's not going to help you learn better English.